# Irreducible representations of $C^*$ algebras and Commutants

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$- algebra and let $\pi: A\to B(H)$ be a representation. Then we know that $\pi$ is irreducible if and only if $\pi(A)'$ are scalars. Is it true that $\{T \in \pi(A)': 0\leq T \leq I\}$ are scalars implies  the full $\pi(A)'$ are scalars?

Since $\pi(A)'$ is a von Neumann algebra, it is spanned by projections. Projections are positive contractions and so we can conclude that $\pi(A)'$ are scalars if $\{T \in \pi(A)': 0\leq T \leq I\}$ are scalars. Is the argument correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.  You could also argue that every $C^*$-algebra is generated by its positive elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is correct, but you don't even need to talk about von Neumann algebras. For any C$^*$-algebra $A$, you have
$$
A=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{a\in A:\ 0\leq a\leq 1\}. 
$$
This a straightforward consequence of the continuous functional calculus, since you always have
$$
a=a_1-a_2+i(a_3-a_4)
$$
with $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ positive.